# Model with unknown number of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

I want to create a Model "Test" that can have anywhere from 2 to 200 questions. There will be many tests. Each test will have different variations of questions.

I was thinking of making an attribute called "questions_ids". I would have to make a string that delimited question_ids by commas.

Or I could make the Model with 200 question_id attributes. This would make the question_id(s) easier and faster to retrieve.

Is there another way? Which is preferred? What if I have 1,000 questions? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with the question ids?  You should already have a method called question_ids which is dynamically created by rails when you call has_many :questions in the Test class.  It will return the ids as an array of integers.

Comment: Why not have `test_id` on Question?

Comment: @Bulezim There will be around a hundred Tests

Comment: @Swards The question_ids will be used to populate the Test. There will be many tests which all use different variations of questions.

Comment: @DDDD - if you're using rails in a common way, the Test would has_many :questions.  And Question would belongs_to :test.  A test_id would be on question (as Bulezim said).  Throw an index on test_id and this will be extremely fast.  Also, you will naturally get the method you probably want \@test.questions.  This will allow you to access these objects in a view and render them without doing explicit SQL using an id array.

Comment: @Swards How do you throw an index on test_id? I am not sure what this means. Also, if a Question belongs_to :test how would the question belong to many tests?

Comment: If the question could belong to many tests, you'd have another table to handle the joins 'test_questions'.  It would have a test_id, question_id columns.  Test would have many test_questions.  Test_question would belong to test and belong to question. Question would have many tests.

Comment: @Swards Then that would be an answer. Can you post an answer on how have another table to handle the joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models/test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_questions
end
```

models/test_question.rb

```
class TestQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :test
end
```

models/question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
end
```

db/migrate/initial_migration.rb

```
class InitialMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

    create_table :tests do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :test_questions do |t|
      t.references :table
      t.references :question
    end

    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

  end
```

This will also create appropriate indexes.